How to add both date and text validation?
I'm trying to allow user to input date as an input (ex: 30/10/2024) or text (ex: Received).
How to use data validation here?
I wasn't able to get to any solution...I'm basing one condition on these columns it's becoming difficult and since it's a manual input there might be backlash with team needing to update multiple columns

Use either of these two formulas for the data validation
The formula checks whether the value contains either a valid Date or the text as "Received"
=IF(OR(ISDATE(J14), J14="RECEIVED"), TRUE, FALSE)

While
This formula validates if the value you entered is either DATE or TEXT.
=OR(ISDATE(J14),ISTEXT(J14))

Sample Outputs:
Result on the first formula:

Result on the second formula:

Note: Adjust your data range based on your needs and also edit the ranges in the given formulas
I have found this Non Official Google Documentation that could help you learn more about setting up a Data Validation in General as Well.
how to set Data validation
References:

ISDATE
ISTEXT


Hi @Vismay Raj, Feel free to accept my answer if you’re satisfied on the expected result.

Got it...thanks!

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
